# Detect Finger Hover Event in an HTML Page

Tags: javascript, android, html, hover, galaxy

The android API allows us to catch the "finger hover" event when developing Java apps for the Samsung Galaxy S4.

I'd like to develop an HTML5 page that catches this event as well,

How can this be done ?

Comment: i know hover is picked up in CSS, but i havn't seen anything specific in JS, maybe onmouseover() or touchstart() can work for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's example of mouse hove(finger)

css:

```
#div1{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
#div1:hover
{
    opacity:0.5;
    cursor:pointer;

}
```

u can see my code result in :http://jsfiddle.net/ashi2009/gXqLd/
or see:http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/html5-mobile-web-touch-events